# print content of <iframe> which exceeds one page

Tags: javascript, iframe, media-queries, dom-events, printing-web-page

in my react application I have an `iframe` which is loaded with HTML document and content of it exceeds 1 page. on pressing `Ctrl+p` I want to print it in several pages but the print preview only shows one page.

how it should be handled to recognize that the content of `iframe` is more than one A4 page?

the DOM in chrome devtool looks like

```
<div class="article-container">
  <iframe style="">#document
   /* hundreds of <p> tags */
  </iframe>
</div>
```

the structure in react app is like

```
   <div className="article-container">
      <FrameText content={content} status={!this.state.editStatus} />
   </div>
```

and the FrameText

```
class FrameText extends React.Component<Props> {
  iframe: HTMLIFrameElement;
  compinentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeprint',(e)=>{console.log(e);})
  }
  /* other stuff*/
  render() {
      const { status } = this.props;
      return <iframe ref={(ref) => (this.iframe = ref!)} style={!status ? { display: 'none' } : {}} />;
  }
```

so here when the `ctrl+p` is pressed I get the event and the iframe document is in the event. Also, I have the content of iframe in the local state too.

I could not find anywhere that when this event is triggered what can I do with it to manipulate or somehow tell the print preview that the content is long.

Also, the css is

```
@media print {
  .article-container {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}
```

Comment: A somewhat dirty hack but maybe sufficient: If you know approximately the number of pages, you could estimate how high the iFrame has to be in Pixels, and set it in the print-css, like 4000px or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your print media query will not work on iframe inner content that is the reason iframe size is ignored while printing If you want to apply specific print styles to iframe then you have to reference from outside via appropriate method(whether js or html) I am writing a sample to reference styles to iframe there may exist other implementations for it to

```
let cssLink = document.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
frames['iframe1'].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for hint, but what should be the content of that custom js or css that shows height/length of the content?

Comment: Make a css file with only one class @media print {
  iframe {
   
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
}

Comment: not exactly if you see the class it is on iframe tag not on the enclosing div

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print multiple pages in an iframe by capturing the CTRL P event, giving focus to the iframe then initiating printing on the iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="2.html"></iframe>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 80) {
            window.frames["iframe"].focus();
            window.frames["iframe"].print();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this and still the same, of course without JQuery. I don't want to use JQuery because of only one function

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi did you at least try it with JQuery, for no other reason than to at least see if the concept works? I tried it with a 4 page iframe and it printed (to PDF) correctly.

Comment: no I have not, actually the same thing can be applied on i.e `componentDidMount` with adding event lister for es6 `onBeforePrint()`  but as I have added other listeners to iframe like onload, on cancel or print when the print preview window closes those listneres return null and app craches. so I dont think even JQuery will help me. besides that it is the project manager decision to add new library or not :)